# IntelXDK Cordova iframe Phone Call

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova, iframe

I'm developing an app in IntelXDK using an iframe. Everything is working fine, PHP and MySQL connection, but the app can't make phone calls.

I try "tel:32939203" and "callto: 32939203", and try JavaScript `window.location` and `window.open`, but it doesn't work. How can I fix that error?

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Phone calls in Intel's XDK can only be made if you have the correct permissions enabled (in the app's config). You also need to be running the app in cross-walk or have installed a compiled version of your app.